# Installing Adobe AIR: Wrong Architecture! What do I do?

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, adobe-air

I'm trying to install Adobe AIR on ubuntu 10.04 by getting the .deb package from [here](http://get.adobe.com/air/), but I get an error message: "Error: Wrong architecture 'i386'".

I am using an AMD Athlon 64 X2 processor, which seems to be a problem. Is there not a 64 bit version of AIR?

Answer (score 0):

There are some instructions here for Ubuntu Linux 9, which will hopefully work for you:

Install Adobe AIR 2 on 64-bit Linux distributions
  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/521/cpsid_52132.html#main_ins_air2_64bit_ubuntu904